# ¿Cómo alinear el texto dentro de un div con un icono de Font Awesome de forma que el icono quede en medio del texto?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5, font-awesome, md-bootstrap

```
<footer class="p-3 text-white-50">

    <div class="container">

      Este sitio es una maquetación no funcional creada usando kit de interfaz de usuario: Material Design for Bootstrap
      <span><i class="fab fa-mdb fa-2x"></i></span> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis amet repellendus esse tempore quisquam omnis dignissimos id ex temporibus eligendi itaque alias ab, obcaecati ipsum doloribus minima ullam. Possimus, perferendis?

    </div>
    
</footer>
```

Estoy utilizando Material Design for Bootstrap 5, he intentado hacer que el texto quede alineado respecto al icono de Font Awesome que tengo en el texto pero no encuentro manera, he intenado con display Flex, buscado en Google e incluso le pregunté a un bot con IA pero no hay manera, tambien busco eliminar el espacio que tiene arriba y abajo el icono. Si alguien sabe cómo le agredezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar las clases de `Bootstrap` para la [alineación vertical](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/vertical-align/).

#### Ejemplo:

```
<span class="align-middle"><i class="fab fa-mdb fa-2x"></i></span>
```

#### Demo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-AyOHI/tIMgoG+32apAs3OdqFowPSDqiz5vLcD2wdhBJ4J/xF1PI6UITcyhS5HCmsiioapRaONqYBvimxzFfnoA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<footer class="p-3 text-black-50">

  <div class="container">

    Este sitio es una maquetación no funcional creada usando kit de interfaz de usuario: Material Design for Bootstrap
    <span class="align-middle"><i class="fab fa-mdb fa-2x"></i></span> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis amet repellendus esse tempore quisquam omnis dignissimos id ex temporibus eligendi itaque alias ab, obcaecati ipsum doloribus minima
    ullam. Possimus, perferendis?

  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias  funciona muy bien, el único inconveniente son los márgenes arriba y debajo del icono, pero entiendo que ya eso es cosa de font awesome 

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R, si, pero es más bien resultado del `font-size` que se le aplica por utilizar `fa-2x`. Si te interesa una solución podes crear una nueva pregunta